# Populate a new dataframe columns with values using a for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I am using RStudio to write a script that simply populates  a new column in a data.frame based upon a simple formula involving another column in the same data.frame. I eventually want to add an internal loop, which is why I think a for loop is the way to go. I am new to r so I am not sure.
At some point in the development of the user defined function, BD, PS and LT (see below) will be arguments in a user defined function. I created a very simple data.frame for illustration.
The question is: How do I get this loop or some formula that will populate the values of media_stock with the simple exponential decay formula in the loop?

```
TV = data.frame(cbind(cable = c(215, 144, 66, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 77, 99, 108, 86, 118, 204, 119, 144, 0, 0, 0, 450, 361, 438, 170, 244, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 107, 122, 207, 274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 752, 700,665),media_stock = NA))

PS = 0.30 
BD = 0 
LT = 6 

for(i in (LT+1):length(TV)){ 
  TV$media_stock[i-BD] <- TV$cable[i-BD] + PS*TV$media_stock[i-BD-1]
}
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two small mistakes in your current code that might fix your problem. The first is that you are using `length(TV)` to get at the number of rows in your data frame. What you want to use for this is `nrow(TV)` instead. The second is that all your value in the `media_stock` column are `NA`. When you apply your formula, no matter what you do to it arithmetically, the result will still be `NA`, so you need to initialize the first value of `media_stock` that you plan to use in your iteration. For example:

```
TV$media_stock[LT-BD] <- 1
for(i in (LT+1):nrow(TV)){ 
  TV$media_stock[i-BD] <- TV$cable[i-BD] + PS*TV$media_stock[i-BD-1]
}
```

Comment: Thank you sebkopf. I will try this and see what happens.